# Add new series[0].data into already existing highchart

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

My chart is created in backend as object and pushed to twig like "{{ chart(myChart) }}". But I need to update data dynamically in it. So I creating new chart and push only chart->series[0] into through ajax.

I've tried update() and setData() methods but have no luck yet, I see "No data to display". Strange thing that if I load same object - data showed.

```
var dchart = $("#myChart").highcharts();
        console.log(dchart);
        var dp = $('body').find(".date-picker");
        dp.datepicker();
        dp.on('changeDate', function(e)
        {
            console.log(e.format('yyyy-m-d'));
            $.ajax({
                url: 'path',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { date: e.format('yyyy-m-d') }

            }).done(function(msg){
                dchart.series[0].setData(msg[0].data);}
```

Comment: have you verified that the data being returned is valid and in proper format?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rewrite your code like this:

```
dchart.series[0].update({
    data: msg[0].data
}, true);
```

Comment: Thank you. But I've already tried this solution. Same result.

Comment: @KonstantinPelikhovsky Have you tried `dchart.redraw()` directly after?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
chart.addSeries();
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/hb2jj/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should inform `$.ajax()`, that data is in JSON format, otherwise you will get string. Or parse string to JSON:

```
dchart.series[0].setData(JSON.parse(msg[0].data));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out that the problem was in xAxis.

The data loaded in timestamp which is out of time range set up in initial chart. That's why it showed `No data to display`.

The solution was to update xAxis:

`dchart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max);`